# javascript draw a image on canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I try to build a javascript code, to draw a image on canvas, but I don't know where go wrong.
That is my code:

```
<body>
<canvas id = "my_canvas"></canvas>
<script>
function setup(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById('my_canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = 800;
    canvas.height = 600;
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = 'a.png';
    ctx.drawImage(image,5,5);
};
window.onload = setup;
setup();

</script>
```

The question is, if I put a line of code `setup();` at end then the image is correctly draw, I don't know why.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your HTML code too? Also, are you getting any errors in the browser's console? that's a good place to start.

And... what is your question??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that `image` is loaded asynchronously, so if you set the source and draw it immediately then the image bits are not yet available and nothing is drawn.

You have to wait for the image to load before being able to draw it on a canvas.

Changing the code to

```
image.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(image, 5, 5);
};
image.src = "a.png";
```

should work as expected.

Answer (score 3):

The image is loading asynchronously.  This code will work:

JavaScript:

```
function setup(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = 800;
    canvas.height = 600;
    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(image,5,5);
    };
    image.src = 'a.png';
}
window.onload = setup;
```